# Android test sharding with spoon/Fork

Tags: android, android-testing, ui-testing, spoon, test-runner

I want to divide the test suite and run the tests on multiple devices to speed up the total tests execution time. I have tried Fork, but it doesn't seem to be as stable as spoon for me.
This is the spoon test runner command I am using and it runs all the tests in the package,whereas it should just run the tests in the shard 2.

```
java \
   -jar "jars/spoon-runner-1.1.10-jar-with-dependencies.jar" \
   --apk  "${APK}" \
   --test-apk "${TEST_APK}" \
   --e package=${package_name} \
   --e numShards=4 \
   --e shardIndex=2 \
```

Comment: Test sharding was broken with support lib test runner 0.3, please update to a later version of the runner and it should work as you specified.